# How to load and display json files list from folder automatically in angularjs or nodejs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, node.js

I am doing one task like I am loading sample `json` files data list in `dropdown` box and it's data is displaying in the textarea for the selected `json` file from `dropdown` list(It's working fine).

But my requirement is: I want to load all these `json` files automatically from a folder(say: I have a `test` folder and it is having all these json files) instead of adding all these files separately with `$http.get()` in the code manually in my application, and these files list should be populated in `dropdown` box automatically, so if I select any json file from that `dropdown` list then it's data should be displayed in the `textarea`.

Please note that if I add any few more `json` files in the same `test` folder in the future then those list also should be populated in the dropdown box automatically.  Please let me know that how can I do this ?

Sample [Plkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/9csuRepgTq9afMClVnGH) is created.

Comment: Angular is a client side library. Getting files from file directories is a backend capability. You can read files from directory at backend and send the list of files at frontend as options in select list. at the front end, you need to write only one common get request for getting the data of selected file.

Comment: @DevidasKadam, is it possible with node.js ?

Comment: yeah you can do this in nodejs.

Comment: @DevidasKadam, can I know any examples on it please ? as I am new to node.js.

Comment: Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819193/how-to-list-all-file-name-from-a-folder-using-angular-js

Comment: Make the first request to server on document load to get the list files.

Answer (score -1):

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GmbtthTWkqdGHldgmJNK?p=preview)

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Select json from drowdown: </p>
    <select name="jsonfilenames" ng-model="selectedjson" ng-change="optionChanged()">

     <option ng-repeat= "file in JSONFiles track by $index" value={{file}}>test{{$index+1}}</option>

   </select>


   <div style="display: flex">
    <div class="container">
        <h4 for="textarea1">Selected json data:</h4>
        <textarea id="textarea1" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
       {{textAreaData}} </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Have a ng-repeat, which track `JSONFiles` array and updates select control options each time array is updated

Comment: I am getting already selected json data in the textarea box from dropdown, But I need it automatically load all my json files list and if I select then selected json data should be displayed in textarea box.

Comment: Try this http://plnkr.co/edit/GmbtthTWkqdGHldgmJNK?p=preview. First it adds 3 files then after 2 seconds it adds a forth file. You Can keep adding options and JSON files as and when you get then from backend.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes from UI wise this plnkr is perfect and the remaining is how to list out the files only instead of giving manually ?(either can be from folder with node or angularjs )

Comment: From UI lets say every 3 seconds you have to send a request to backend. You should have a backend implementation which look into folder and retrieves all the JSON files and returns them back to UI. Then you have to update the JSONFiles array

Comment: I have one query, May I know that you are available, I am getting my files list from my back-end, but I am not sure how can I display those in my UI ? Created at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849899/how-to-send-list-of-files-to-angularjs-options-from-node-js  Please let me know and Thanks in advance.