# How to send list of files to angularjs options from node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, node.js, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting files from directory('`app/jsonfiles`') in `node.js`, and I am not sure how can I send this list of files to my `front-end` as options in `select` list to write one common get request for getting the data of selected file.

partial [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hzBzyXlW7GD1xlfvNvDS?p=preview). Please let me know that how can I get my list of files in my angular from my server.js to display in my dropdown and Thanks in advance for help !

Comment: Currently, are you able to get data from backend?

Comment: @Ravi Teja, yes, I am getting those filenames and it's data on my console(you can check in server.js as I mentioned):  console.log(filename); and console.log(data[filename]);

Answer (score 0):

Inject `Main` service into `MainCtrl` and call the service.

```
  var app = angular.module('plunker', [MainService]);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http, $timeout, Main) {
    $scope.JSONFiles = [];

    Main.get().success(function(data){
     data.forEach(function(obj){
      $scope.JSONFiles.push(obj);
     })
     });
    $scope.selectedjson ="";
    $scope.textAreaData = "";
    $scope.optionChanged = function(){
      $scope.textAreaData = $scope.selectedjson;
    }

    });
```

Comment: it's saying that Unexpected token {(at Main.get().success(data){ ) and hence MainCtrl is not a function, got undefined error is coming.

Comment: Main.get().success(function(data){
              data.forEach(function(obj){
               $scope.JSONFiles.push(obj);
              })
              });
             //});
             $scope.selectedjson ="";
             $scope.textAreaData = "";
             $scope.optionChanged = function(){
               $scope.textAreaData = $scope.selectedjson;
             } Giving data.forEach is not a function (and one more: } is added extra in the above script, and I removed extra }, checked, getting data.forEach is not a function error. please find)

Comment: yes, I have tried the above, I am getting: TypeError: data.forEach is not a function error.

Comment: Can try to put a debugger point at `data.forEach` and see whether `data` is populated.. with data from backend?